# How do I determine the location of missing references/resolve this linking issue when compiling Wine specifically en route to Roblox on Linux?

Tags: linux, roblox, wine

I was recently able to get my son to finally agree to try out Linux on his personal machine, based on the availability of freshly issued guides on how to get *Roblox* working under *Wine*.  I was a bit optimistic, and dove in head first.  Of course, nothing is going as it was supposed to; the instructions I've been following didn't even have a list of dependencies, though I thought I'd muddled through locating and installing most of them.

FYI: the machine is running *Ubuntu 21.10*, no packages other than a few for system administration had been added to the default install until I went about locating what was necessary to build Wine.  The machine is an i7 w/16GB of RAM, just under a TB of drive space (spinning, not SSD), and notably causing a bit of complexity for this issue is the fact that it's utilizing an *AMD Radeon RX 580* video card (and thus Vulkan drivers w/Wine, or so the guide tells me).  It should also be noted that this is using a custom build of wine ([wine-tkg](https://github.com/Frogging-Family/wine-tkg-git)), and the [Grapejuice](https://gitlab.com/brinkervii/grapejuice) wine+roblox management application in order to deal with a couple of previous bugs when using wine to execute roblox..

The guide that I'm following does not mention the linking issue that I am having specifically at any point, but it is also being implemented on another linux variant-- Arch, if I remember correctly, but with the disclaimer that debian, ubuntu, and the other side of the tree aren't much more complicated, each with complimentary scripts to execute.  It's available at [this YouTube link (sorry)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlziv2nghZ0).

*configure* seems to execute without any issues as part of the script to be utilized under Ubuntu, but after a lengthy stretch of compiling source, this happens when it's in the process of linking:

```
tools/winegcc/winegcc -o dlls/wintrust/wintrust.dll.so --wine-objdir . -m64 -fPIC -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -shared \
  ../wine-mirror-git/dlls/wintrust/wintrust.spec -mno-cygwin dlls/wintrust/asn.o \
  dlls/wintrust/crypt.o dlls/wintrust/register.o dlls/wintrust/softpub.o \
  dlls/wintrust/wintrust_main.o dlls/wintrust/version.res dlls/cryptui/libcryptui.a \
  dlls/imagehlp/libimagehlp.a dlls/crypt32/libcrypt32.a dlls/user32/libuser32.a \
  dlls/advapi32/libadvapi32.a dlls/winecrt0/libwinecrt0.a dlls/ucrtbase/libucrtbase.a \
  dlls/kernel32/libkernel32.a dlls/ntdll/libntdll.a -Wl,-delayload,cryptui.dll \
  -Wl,-delayload,imagehlp.dll -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/desktop.o: in function `X11DRV_create_desktop':
desktop.c:(.text+0xcd3): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/window.o: in function `create_whole_window':
window.c:(.text+0x2b19): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/window.o: in function `map_window':
window.c:(.text+0x31c0): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/window.o: in function `make_window_embedded':
window.c:(.text+0x3427): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/window.o: in function `X11DRV_CreateWindow':
window.c:(.text+0x491f): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/x11drv_main.o: in function `x11drv_init_thread_data':
x11drv_main.c:(tools/winegcc/winegcc -o dlls/winusb/winusb.dll.so --wine-objdir . -m64 -fPIC -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -shared \
  ../wine-mirror-git/dlls/winusb/winusb.spec -mno-cygwin dlls/winecrt0/libwinecrt0.a \
  dlls/ucrtbase/libucrtbase.a dlls/kernel32/libkernel32.a dlls/ntdll/libntdll.a -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed
.text+0x1611): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_init'  
/usr/bin/ld: x11drv_main.c:(.text+0x165e): undefined reference to `x11drv_xinput_enable'
/usr/bin/ld: dlls/winex11.drv/winex11.drv.so: hidden symbol `x11drv_xinput_init' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I haven't been able to turn up any information on where to find those missing symbols, though admittedly my google-fu is not the best.  I'd be very grateful for anything that anyone might be able to offer regarding how I might go about resolving this, and I assure you my son would be as well.  Please let me know if any more information regarding the machine's configuration is necessary.  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It took me some effort, but I think I found it. The missing symbols are from Wine itself, and those are missing because X11/extensions/XInput2.h is missing, so those functions are not being compiled. I fixed it in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt install libxi-dev
```